# Referencing Parameterized Index method in ASP.NET MVC Returns Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, nunit, specflow

I am writing tests using SpecFlow and ASP.NET MVC and the code steps are perfectly fine. However, I wanted to write tests based on the validation on the model.

In my HomeController (for a login screen), the Index() method is implemented twice, both with different method signatures:

```
// When the page is initially loaded, the value of null is passed to 
// the parameter. This would prompt the view to load the login-screen. 
public ActionResult Index(string u) {
    // some declaration
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(myobject o) {
    // some declaration
    return View(model);
}

// No default implementation for Index() 

public string SomeSampleFunction() {
    return "This is a test string";
}
```

When I write my tests, every reference to the Index() method retuns null. I tried doing such as:

```
var _controller = new HomeController();
var _result = _controller.Index("") as ViewResult;
// The succeeding line also returns null
// var _result = _controller.Index(string.empty) as ViewResult;
Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(_result);
Assert.IsEmpty(((ViewResult)_result).ViewName);
Assert.AreEqual("Log In", homeController.ViewData["Title"], "Page title is wrong");
```

Am I missing something on this one? The references to the Index() method is always null but if I call an ordinary method such as "SomeSampleFunction", it works just fine. Any help?

Comment: Try making the Index method string parameter optional, and instead of passing a string in your tests don't pass it anything.

Comment: I think it won't work well either. If I change the Index method to an optional string parameter, I need a default value which is null.

If I change my controller to something like:

`public ActionResult Index(string u = null) { }`

The following calls would be just the same:

`var _result = _controller.Index() as ViewResult;`
`var _result = _controller.Index(u:null) as ViewResult;`

Comment: Have you tried putting a `[FromBody]` attribute to your parameter with the object? It is possible that Routing gets confused on which method to use since both of them have one parameter which it assumes it would take from the URI

Comment: I haven't tried that but I am not sure if the Routing gets confused considering that the second declaration has a HttpPost attribute. 

One thing I am looking as well is that there could probably be an issue with overloaded controller methods.

Comment: @Patrick: You are casting ActionResult to ViewResult using the `as` keyword. Try `(ViewResult)_controller.Index("")` to see if it throws an `InvalidCastOperationException`. I wonder if the return value of your Index method is actually an object, but the cast fails, returning null.

Comment: i'm also facing same issue any answer?